# How to set classpath for com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource

Tags: java, sql, mysql, glassfish, mysql-connector

I want to deploy application called "banksmart" in glassfish application server.

This step is done for database connection for banksmart deployment.

I am getting the following error when I ping in glassfish from here:

[image]

```
Ping Connection Pool failed for banksmart. Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource Please check the server.log for more details.
```

Here's the JDBC Resources settings:

[image]

Here's the JDBC connection pools settings:

[image]
[image]

Here's the server.log logfile.

```
[2023-04-23T17:53:59.428+0545] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [jdbc.exc_cnfe_ds] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.gjc.util] [tid: _ThreadID=312 _ThreadName=admin-listener(45)] [timeMillis: 1682251739428] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  RAR5099 : Wrong class name or classpath for Datasource Object
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder.getDataSourceObject(DataSourceObjectBuilder.java:285)
        at com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder.constructDataSourceObject(DataSourceObjectBuilder.java:114)
        at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.getDataSource(ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1300)
        at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:163)
        at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:102)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.getUnpooledConnection(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:702)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.testConnectionPool(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:431)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.pingConnectionPool(ConnectorRuntime.java:1162)
        at org.glassfish.connectors.admin.cli.PingConnectionPool.execute(PingConnectionPool.java:143)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:253)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:231)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateExecCommand.executeCommandLegacyFormat(TemplateExecCommand.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateCommandGetResource.processGetLegacyFormat(TemplateCommandGetResource.java:75)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor152.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:365)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
]]

[2023-04-23T17:53:59.449+0545] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [test.connection.pool.failed] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service] [tid: _ThreadID=312 _ThreadName=admin-listener(45)] [timeMillis: 1682251739449] [levelValue: 900] [[
  RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ banksmart ], Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource]]

[2023-04-23T17:53:59.459+0545] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [org.glassfish.admingui] [tid: _ThreadID=311 _ThreadName=admin-listener(44)] [timeMillis: 1682251739459] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  RestResponse.getResponse() gives FAILURE.  endpoint = 'https://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/ping-connection-pool.json'; attrs = '{id=banksmart}']]
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems.

The jarfile is in the wrong place. Should be in the /lib not lib/ext.

You have the wrong jar. You need [mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/8.0.33/mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar) or possibly an older version. sqljdbc is for ms sqlserver.

Something else that looks off is that your Resource Type is `XADataSource` but you have selected a non XA driver class. They need to match. I suspect you want `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource`

Comment: Few questions:
1) What's the alternative of sqljdbc for mysql?
2) Do I need to place all jars into /lib?

Comment: 1) as per my answer: mysql-connector-j.jar - you can pull the v8.0.33 from the link. You may need an older version 2) yes

Comment: Still not fixed. Same error: Ping Connection Pool failed for banksmart. Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource Please check the server.log for more details.

Comment: FInd out which lib folder in your application server jars should go. It's not lib/ext. It may be higher than /home/banksmart/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib. Application server may need a restart, or at least the domain.

Comment: When I try to restart the domain, I get this error: [banksmart@localhost bin]$ ./asadmin restart-domain domain1
NCLS-ADMIN-00010
Server is not running, will attempt to start it...
There is a process already using the admin port 4848 -- it probably is another instance of a GlassFish server.
Command restart-domain failed.

Comment: Before you restart, stop it first

Comment: I get server not running when I try to stop it: `NCLS-ADMIN-00010
CLI306: Warning - The server located at /home/banksmart/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1 is not running.
Command stop-domain executed successfully.`

Comment: http://192.168.169.128:8080/ but glassfish server is running at this port.

Comment: Maybe a new question - how do i restart a glassfish domain server?

Comment: I restarted the glassfish domain server. Still the same error applies.`Ping Connection Pool failed for banksmart. Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource Please check the server.log for more details.
`

Comment: It's the right jar - see https://jar-download.com/artifacts/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.11/source-code/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/MysqlXADataSource.java. I have no idea why you classpath won't pick it up. That's where you need to be googling.

Comment: There's no answer on google, looks like I'm the only one with this issue.

Comment: Check the ping checkbox in the console and save the changes.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant that step isn't working

Comment: The issue is fixed! Finally! Ping succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I put everything mentioned in another answer so I recommend you follow that answer.

The most important things to do are:

1. Include all those `.jar` files in both `lib` directories that exist.
2. Add a new property in JDBC connection pool settings: `"useSSL"` and set its value to `false`.

After you do this, you'll get some obvious error messages, but those shouldn't be that hard to fix.

Comment: No criticism intended , that's an old grubby fix aka quick fix method. I know those well, older servers usually use "shared libraries" e.g. "commons/lib" for all the domains in the one server and JVM.